# Homework Question Flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, close-reasons, homework

Can we have a "flag as homework question" button where we can effectively put a question on hold for X days in the even that we see a question that is blatantly a homework/assignment question and the ask-er has not even attempted to do any of the work themselves?

Comment: YES! 'Do my homework for me' questions are beyond irritating, the laziness from some of these people is obvious (I am a teacher and know that giving answers does not help them learn).

Comment: No, questions are questions *regardless of the motivations of the asker*; if they are off-topic vote them as off-topic, but if well asked treat them like *any other question*. It is our goal to be a knowledge repository, not to be homework help for hire nor do we police school policies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are enough close reasons that apply to homework **with no effort at all**.

You could think of:

- Too broad: if the question is actually an entire homework assignment, it might be too broad. There are too many possible answers.
- Unclear what you are asking: if the *actual problem* with that assignment isn't clear. The assignment can be a copy-paste, and the OP didn't mention very clear where his understanding stops.
- On SO, we also have a close reason for debugging help. That one could apply too if the question states 'it doesn't work', but doesn't have some code to reproduce the question.
- A custom close reason you can enter yourself.

Note that strictly homework questions are allowed, as long as they follow the site rules. This isn't a site for just the elite / working class.

Comment: I wouldnt say that this site is for 'elite/working class' although I feel the need to at least do something to help the next generation of programmers learn and not 'slide by' because the ones that 'fake it' once they land their first job and sometimes end up on my team, 
for example I had one junior developer come straight from university, spent 7 days on a algorithm to convert time in Milliseconds to H:M:S format, after that amount of time it turns out that not only did he ask someone else from another team 'help' with the work, and he was sure that 12e-1 was a bug because he had never seen

Comment: @DamianNikodem: I understand. But as said, there is enough in place already.

Comment: Also, there is the issue of school/university students getting an assignment and going to one or some SE sites with their homework - trying to get other people to complete their homework for them (note, I ***know*** not all homework questions are like this) - this is cheating.

Comment: @SabreTooth: Yes, I have burned down some of those questions and then OP said "my teacher told me to go here and post this"... That doesn't really help...

Comment: @PatrickHofman I agree, however, many teachers probably did not say this and some may be encouraging students to contribute questions to the site, at the same time getting the information that will help them go further.  I don't do this explcitly, but allow students to search the threads here and tell them that they are not to try to get people to write the answers for them (they have not figured that I am a member - my name is not really Sabre Tooth ;) )

Comment: @SabreTooth: I know, Mr. D :)

Comment: "Mr. D." .... *giggles*